# Getting wrong output while calculating Cross entropy loss using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, cross-entropy

Getting wrong output while calculating Cross entropy loss using pytorch

Hi guys ,
I calculated the cross entropy loss using pytorch , Input = torch.tensor([[1.,0.0,0.0],[1.,0.0,0.0]])  ,label = torch.tensor([0, 0]) . The output must be 0 but I got ( tensor(0.5514) ) . Anyone Plz say why it's coming 0.55 instead of 0 [code for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zliR9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are getting the correct output.

```
import torch
Input = torch.tensor([[1.,0.0,0.0],[1.,0.0,0.0]])
label = torch.tensor([0, 0])

print(torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(Input,label))
# tensor(0.5514)
```

`torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy` function combines `log_softmax` and `nll_loss` in a single function:

It is equivalent to :

```
torch.nn.functional.nll_loss(torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(Input, 1), label)
```

Code for reference:

```
print(torch.nn.functional.softmax(Input, 1).log())
tensor([[-0.5514, -1.5514, -1.5514],
        [-0.5514, -1.5514, -1.5514]])

print(torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(Input, 1))
tensor([[-0.5514, -1.5514, -1.5514],
        [-0.5514, -1.5514, -1.5514]])

print(torch.nn.functional.nll_loss(torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(Input, 1), label))
tensor(0.5514)
```

Now, you see:

`torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(Input,label)`     is equal to

`torch.nn.functional.nll_loss(torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(Input, 1), label)`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and one more thing can we use softmax at the last layer? if we use cross entropy for loss calculation

Comment: I think we can.. but, please double check I am not sure. Also, if this solution answers your question please accept it as an answer.